# Making div animate and appear rotating clockwise.i.e radialwipe clock effect for Div

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

I have been googling for a appear effect of div like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QMZg2/).
Here image is drawn using `< canvas >`
"**radialwipe clock effect** "
How can I achieve this.
I found [this](http://www.netzgesta.de/transm/eyewitness.html) javascript library.  But it provides this effect for image only.
I need the same effect for div.
What are the approaches to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an 1/2 clock animation effect which is similar to the one you want. I hope to find the solution to provide an exact animation.

### Code

You need some markup for the animation:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    This is a good day. Maybe.
  </div>
  <div class="rotate"></div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
</div>
```

- **wrapper** - is used to set the position of the content
- **content** - your content in a div (or any other element)
- **rotate** - animation to simulate the 1/2 clock
- **mask** - animation to hide the `content`

And this is the CSS (written in [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)):

#### Variables

```
$width: 200px;
$height: 200px;
$duration: 2s;
$delay: 1s;
$color-alpha: #308991;
$color-beta: #80c144;
$color-gamma: #b83d54;

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.content {
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  background: $color-beta;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
}

/* Rotates 360 deg */
.rotate {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: $width / 2;
  height: $height;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .15em $color-alpha;
  background: $color-alpha;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  animation: rotate $duration linear 1 forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0%   { 
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  62% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  99.99% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

/* The .content is hidden by .mask until the .rotate reveals it */
.mask {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  width: $width + 2px;
  height: $height + 2px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(top, transparent 50%, $color-alpha 50%),
    linear-gradient(top, $color-alpha 50%, transparent 50%);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top, transparent 50%, $color-alpha 50%),
    linear-gradient(to top, $color-alpha 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-position:100% 100%, 0 0;
  background-size: 50% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 .65em $color-alpha;

  animation: mask $duration / 1.25 linear 1 forwards; 
  animation-delay: (-$duration / 7.5) + $delay;
}

@keyframes mask {
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 0, 0 0;
  }

  99.99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0, 0 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

### Demo

You can see an live demo on CodePen: [1/2 clock animation](http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/jqpog)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [transform: rotate(n deg)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood, then. The "radialwipe clock effect" made my think you just wanted the div to rotate... My bad.
AFAIK there is no way to achieve the effect you want on a div.

Answer (score 0):

This script can convert html to image.
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you're looking for a pie timer effect. Here is a pure CSS one I did a while ago: http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/.

Comment: Thanks.But this wont work for pie images with elliptical shape.I implemented this using my own logic of drawing elliptical arc and HTML5 canvas.